# Evaluate lambda over grid

Tags: python

```
gridmax, gridsize = 8, 150
grid=linspace(0, gridmax**1e-1, gridsize)**10  
sigma= lambda s:0
```

I want to evaluate the function sigma for all points on the grid. However instead of getting an array of zeroes I am getting just one zero. I want an array of zeroes. Help!

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension

```
grid = [sigma(e) for e in grid]
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.6 us per loop
```

Using numpy's vectorize

```
grid = np.vectorize(sigma)(grid)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.61 ms per loop
```

Or vectorize lambda function:

```
sigma = lambda s: np.zeros(s.shape)
grid = sigma(grid)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 667 ns per loop
```

The vectorized version is obviously the most performant.